# Have this code here, need to copy files from a directory over to mine using scripts

Tags: scripting

So I have an array with some names. 
I need to find all the files in another folder with a certain pattern and copy those files over to my current folder.

```
NAME=(JOHN)
for i in ${NAMES[@]}
do
   cp ~/folder/$i .
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find`:

```
find /yourdir -name '*JOHN*' -exec cp {} ~/folder/  \;
```

[Related question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241625/find-and-copy-files)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one, If your filename is of specified pattern:

```
NAME=(PATTERN1 PATTERN2)
for i in ${NAMES[@]}
do
   find PATH -name "$i" -exec cp -av {} PATH_TO_COPY \;
done
```

If your filename have other string other than PATTERN:

```
NAME=(PATTERN1 PATTERN2)
for i in ${NAMES[@]}
    do
       find PATH -name "*${i}*" -exec cp -av {} PATH_TO_COPY \;
    done
```

make changes as per your need.